# How to register ELResolver in JSF 2.0 Programmatically

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsf, el

While working with Spring 3.x and and JSF 2.x, we can register the Spring Beans EL resolver for JSF in the faces-config.xml as:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

Is there a way we can do this programmatically and get rid of faces-config.xml?

***Edit: 02/27/2012*** 
I found a way to get this working. Not quite sure yet but I'm still reviewing my solution. Here's is how I got it working. 
1.Write a Java Servlet and implement its init() method which contains the code to register ELResolver i.e.

public final class ELResolverInitializerServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ELResolverInitializerServlet.class.getName());

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public ELResolverInitializerServlet() {
    super();
}

/**
 * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
 */
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    LOGGER.info("::::::::::::::::::: Faces context: " + context);
    context.getApplication().addELResolver(new SpringBeanFacesELResolver());

}
```

}

2.Register this servlet using Spring's bootstrapper org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer i.e.

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AppInitializer.class
        .getName());

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    LOGGER.info("Bootstraping Spring...");
            ...

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic elResolverInitializer = servletContext
            .addServlet("elResolverInit",
                    new ELResolverInitializerServlet());
    elResolverInitializer.setLoadOnStartup(2);
            ...
}
```

}

With this configuration, Spring bootstrapper registers the servlet as a loadOnStartup servlet. This servlet is loaded after the JSF's FacesContext is created. Then it adds the ELResolver to the JSF's context which is available for the application after the application starts up.

***Any thoughts / reviews are welcome.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [addELResolver](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/application/Application.html#addELResolver%28javax.el.ELResolver%29) method in `Application` class.
Something like:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().addELResolver(myResolver);
```

Comment: I had the same intuition. That doesn't work. You will always get a null when calling FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(). The solution that I'm looking for is the phase when this setup has to be invoked and the best way that can be done.

Comment: Where do you call it from exactly?

Comment: I call it from my implementation of org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer.onStartup().